# Why doesn't the user type get populated with the data values from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to get started with [GORM](https://gorm.io/) and did a simple select SQL query as shown below. The debug logs show that two records were returned but as I try to inspect the `users` type, it just prints empty. What could be the reason for this? (There is definitely data in the table as shown in the logs which say 2 records returned)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    username string
    password string
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql","root:1234@(localhost)/database_test")
    db.LogMode(true)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to the database")
    }

    var users User
    db.Table("user").Find(&users)
    fmt.Println("after finding the user")
    fmt.Println("user ", users.username)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your fields are not exported.

Comment: @Peter I did not understand. Could you please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field names `username` and `password` start with a lowercase letter, which makes them unexported. Unexported identifiers cannot be accessed from other packages (in this case github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

Rename them to `Username` and `Password` to [export](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) them.